# SQL Server 2008 query to search all stored procedure for a specific parameter name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column `name varchar(8)`....I want to change the size to 20 ...and have almost about 100 stored procedures .

I need to change the size of `@name` in all stored procedures that I have passed name as a parameter.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/11/09/finding-stored-procedures-containing-string.aspx

Answer (score 9):

You can right click on the table and select View Dependancies – this will give you a list of all dependent objects you need to consider for updating.

If you want to search through all columns another tool you can try apart from SQL Search is [ApexSQL Search](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_search.aspx) which is also free.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to find database objects (e.g. tables, columns, triggers) by name - have a look at the **FREE** Red-Gate tool called [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) which does this - it searches your entire database for any kind of string(s).

[image]

[image]

It's a great must-have tool for any DBA or database developer - did I already mention it's absolutely **FREE** to use for any kind of use??

Answer (score 1):

To look for code in the database you can search [sys.sql_modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx) (see example) or use something like [Red Gate SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search) which is free.

You can also use SQL:

```
SELECT
   OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
FROM
   sys.sql_modules
WHERE
   definition like '%whatever%'
```

Note: syscomments is legacy and splits the definition into nvarchar 4000 chunks thus risking *not* finding what you want. The same applies to INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES

Edit: I misunderstood

To find parameters, query [sys.parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176074.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

To see both the Param and SP name:

```
SELECT
   o.name as NAME, p.name as parameter
FROM
   sys.parameters p (NOLOCK)
   INNER JOIN sys.objects o (NOLOCK) ON p.object_id = o.object_id 
WHERE
   p.name like '%afe%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd would use Mangement Studio to generate scripts for all your stored procedures, and then use the text editor to do a simple find or find & verify & replace to make changes, and then just run the script (the whole script) again.